# Am I supposed to seed the first "Admin" user?

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have a website where users can sign-up, log-in and then post posts. Every new registered user receives a normal user role. Am I supposed to seed the first "Admin" user or just change the role of the normal user whom I want to be an admin straight in the database?

Comment: Ideally you want to create an admin account during a setup phase. You could indeed seed it and either let the user pick a password using a setup page, or generate it and send it to the person's mail. Changing it by hand is tedious.

Comment: This isn't the right kind of question for SO. I'm voting to close on "primarily opinion-based". In answer to your question: yes, seed is fine. It really depends on what your first admin's user-experience should be. It also depends on how vulnerable you are making your application if you went a route of "first user registration is promoted to x role".